# Let a(s) be a unit speed plane curve and let b(s) and r(s) be two different involutes of a(s). Prove that b(s) and r(s) are Bertrand Curves.

Tags: differential-geometry

I've solved this problem but I'm not sure if my logics are correct.

sol)
If two curves $b(s)$ and $r(s)$ are involutes of $a(s)$, then

$b(s)$ = $a(s)$ + ($c_1$-$s$)$T_a(s)$ for some constant $c_1$,
($T_a(s)$ is a tangent vector for $a(s)$)

$r(s)$ = $a(s)$ + ($c_2-s$)$T_a(s)$ for some constant $c_2$

differentiating both $b(s)$ and $r(s)$ we get

$b'(s)$= $T_a(s)$+ (-1)$T_a(s)$+($c_1-s$)($kN_a$)=($c_1-s$)($kN_a$)
$r'(s)$=$T_a(s)$+ (-1)$T_a(s)$+($c_2-s$)($kN_a$)=($c_2-s$)($kN_a$)

Two regular curves $b(s)$ and $r(s)$ are Bertrand curves if for each $s$ the normal line to $b(s)$ at $s$ is also the normal line to $r(s)$ at s. This is equivalent to saying ($b(s)$ - $r(s)$) is perpendicular to $b'(s)$ and  ($b(s)$ - $r(s)$) is perpendicular to $r'(s)$ for all $s$

since <$b(s)-r(s)$,$b'(s)$>=$0$ and <$b(s)-r(s)$,$r'(s)$>=$0$
$b(s)$ and $r(s)$ are bertrand curves.

<,> is innerproduct.

I edited the answer.
Any comment or suggestions would help! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is a Bertrand mate?

Comment: Some information [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3642788/305862)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Bertrand mate is same as Bertrand Curves. My textbook uses both of the terms

Comment: Where did your “This is equivalent to …” come from? Also, remember than these are space curves.

Comment: @TedShifrin if two curves have same normal line(i.e N($s_0$)are same at $s_0$, then the tangent vector at $s_0$ would be perpendicular to N$(s_0$) since TNB are orthonormal

Comment: You seem to be thinking that the converse is true — it’s not. You need to compute the principal normals of $b$ and $r$.